# Syntax Error in R.java file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I had placed a text view on my page and i didn't realize I had misspelled the id it was meant to be txtTick but instead I had hit the / and it was txt/tick. I corrected this error however it had saved to my R.java file and i keep getting the error.
Syntax error on token "/" ,, expected. 
However I cant modify this file and I don't want to touch it encase something else happens. I have checked my strings.xml and that string doesn't exist anymore.
I am unable to clean my project because of this error and have tried restarting it as well but  have no idea how I can fix this.
Any ideas?

R.Java

```
 public static final int txt/tick=0x7f050089;
```

xml

```
android:id="@+id/txtTick"
```

Comment: just delete gen folder, it will recreate automatically

Comment: Clean the project. It will re make the R.java file.

Comment: i tried that i just keeps coming back the same way

Comment: it wont allow me to clean because it says there are errors

Comment: I hope there is duplicate id exist in your xml file and do that what subash said.

Comment: try all what others say . ELSE IF ALL DONT WORK -- MAKE NEW ACTIVITY AND DELETE OLD CODE

Answer (score 2):

delete your  'gen' folder rebuild your project another then
simply delete your workspace .metadata file and import your project again and rebuild it

Answer (score 1):

delete R file and then Clean build your project this might work for you..

Answer (score 0):

Delete `R.java`, modify `strings.xml` to include the string that doesn't existed. Rebuild the project and run.

Answer (score 0):

Check `R.java` commentary:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
```

as Varun said, clean and build your project to generate a new `R.java` file

Comment: yes every time i was deleting it, it was generating with the same problem. I cleaned the project deleted the gen file and the same thing happened but I switched the workspace to an old one then back to my current one and deleted the gen again and cleaned it and finially its working again. Thanks everyone for their help